# Read Windows path outside Vagrant file

Tags: python-2.7, vagrant

I want to list file in Windows `C:/Documents` folder, but my program is running in Vagrant. My program code is Python.

My problem is how can I get a list of files in `C:/Documents` when my program is running in Vagrant?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [synced folder](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html)

```
config.vm.synced_folder "c:/Document", "/win_document"
```

and your python code running on vagrant can now take `/win_document` as argument